# Overload resolution with variadic higher order functions

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Lets say I have a variadic higher order function

```
template<typename F, typename ...Args>
void execution(F func, Args&&... args)
{
    func(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Then for this overload set

```
void f() {}
void f(int arg) {}
```

Overload resolution will be [impossible](http://ideone.com/Zezvnw)

```
int main()
{
    execution(f, 1);
    execution(f);
    return 0;
}
```

Yet if only either one of the two is provided, the program [compiles](http://ideone.com/40tknr)

1. Why does this happen ? Why template argument deduction fails?
2. If I remove `f()` from the set and replace it with `f(arg, arg2)` there's still a [problem](http://ideone.com/ATawhs). Is there a workaround, or **do I always have to [provide the type](http://ideone.com/42qoXg) of the function** as a template argument ?

   ```
   execution<void()>(f);
   ```

Comment: Is there a C++ Jon Skeet?

Comment: That's firstly a problem of template argument deduction,  less of overload resolution.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054703/overloaded-function-as-argument-of-variadic-template-function?rq=1 <- looks similar

Comment: The C++1y solution is to write `execution([](auto&&... pp){ return f(std::forward<decltype(pp)>(pp)...); });`. This is a known problem, and I guess this question has multiple duplicates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an overload set object.  This is an object that represents the entire overload set of functions of `f`:

```
struct f_overload_set {
  template<typename...As>
  auto operator()(As&&...as)->
    decltype(f(std::declval<As>()...))
  { return f(std::forward<As>(as)...); }
};
```

now pass `f_overload_set{}` to your `template` function.

`template`s function value arguments must be values, and in current C++ there is no first class value that represents an entire overload set of a function.  The symbol `f` gets disambiguated into one overload at each point of use: but that requires an immediate context at the point of use.  The above defers the disambiguation until we have the arguments handy.

Comment: That solves it . And I thought I had figured out [creating overload sets explicitly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22147375/2567683)

Comment: C++14: `#define LIFT(f) [](auto&&... a) -> decltype(auto){ return f(std::forward<decltype(a)>(a)...); }`. Replace `std::forward` with `static_cast` if you want no dependency on `<utility>`.

Answer (score 8):

When doing template type deduction, the compiler doesn't analyse how the types are used inside the function. Therefore when deducing the template parameters, the compiler sees no relation between the different template arguments. Thus the additional variadic template arguments don't matter at all, and the problem can be reduced to

```
template<typename Func> void execution(Func func);

void f();
void f(int);

execution(f);
```

With this minimized code, it should be obvious why template argument deduction fails.

You can resolve this by making your first argument explicitly dependent on the remaining template arguments, e.g.:

```
template<typename... Args>
 void execution(void (*func)(Args ...), Args ... args)
{
  func(std::forward<Args>(args) ...);
}
```

Comment: `std::function` is *not* required to SFINAE-reject functions that cannot be called for the argument types supplied in the template parameter. This is a QoI issue.

Comment: Additionally, your solution requires an explicit conversion of `f` to a `std::function` type at the call site: Overload resolution between different functions only happens when an explicit target type is given (e.g. `void execution( void(*)(int) );`). The `std::function` types only have constructor templates, therefore no overload resolution will take place and `f` will be ambiguous.

Comment: @dyp: Thank you, I was not aware of the problems with `std::function`. I've changed the code to a simple function pointer; while less flexible, it should resolve the issue at hand.

Comment: `void foo(int);  template<typename Args ...> void execution(void (*func)(Args ...), Args ... args); int main(){ execution( foo, 3.0 ); }` does what?  Ie, this fix is insufficient.

Comment: @Yakk: It gives an error because there's no `f(double)`. Which I'd consider expected behaviour. Which behaviour did you expect?

Comment: @Yakk: I don't see why there would be that requirement. The `3.0` is passed to a deduced type, and therefore no type conversion happens. If you want type conversion to happen on that argument, write `execute<int>(f, 3.0)`. That's templates 101, and not related to that specific usage. In the end, it's no different than the fact that `std::max(1, 2.0)` fails.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific function 'f' available:

Simplifying it:

```
template<typename F>
void execution(F func)
{}

void f() {}
void f(int arg) {}

int main()
{
    execution(f);
    return 0;
}
```

You have two functions 'f' available for template parameter deduction/substitution