# Pass overloaded member function to a variadic template function

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have a class with a function **add**:

```
class Pool {
public:
    Pool() {};
    template<class F, class... A>
    auto add(F&& f, A&&... args) -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F(A...)>::type>
    {
        // return empty placeholder, for the sake of this code example
        std::future<typename std::result_of<F(A...)>::type> ret;
        return ret;
    };
};
```

It should take any function with its arguments, add it to a thread pool and return a future of the result type of that function.

And a class where I use it:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    string doIt(string) { return string("a"); };
    string doIt(int, string) { return string("b"); };

    void test() {
        Pool myPool;
        string a("test");
        myPool.add(&MyClass::doIt, a); // Error
    };
};
```

Which gives a compiler error:

```
Error   1   error C2914: 'Pool::add' : cannot deduce template argument as function argument is ambiguous    MyClass.cpp 94
```

Now the problem is (I think) that the compiler can't deduce which overload I want to use. Similar to [Overloaded function as argument of variadic template function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9054703/overloaded-function-as-argument-of-variadic-template-function).
(Also I'm not 100% clear on why I have to use "&" for class member functions, but no ampersand if I pass in a free function).
Anyway I also tried the workaround mentioned in above answer:

```
struct doIt_wrapper {
    template <typename... T>
    auto operator()(T... args) -> decltype(doIt(args...)) {
        return doIt(args...);
    }
};
```

and then modifying MyClass::test() to:

```
    void test() {
        Pool myPool;
        string a("test");
        myPool.add(doIt_wrapper(), a);
    };
```

But it also gives me a compiler error:

```
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type doIt_wrapper::operator ()(T...)'  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\include\xrefwrap 58
```

I also tried a few variants like `myPool.add(doIt_wrapper<string>()` and with/without '&' but they all generate one or the other compiler error.

I think I don't fully understand the problem yet and I would be glad if someone could shed light on it. Also I am looking for a proper solution to this problem. It can't really be the case that this only works as long as there are no two functions with the same name, and as soon as there are, everything breaks down without a proper, generic solution?

Edit: Fixed a few typos and uploaded a minimal example here: http://ideone.com/eX1r1l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use lambda:

```
myPool.add([this](const std::string& s) {doIt(s);}, a);
```

or even

```
myPool.add([this, a]() {doIt(a);});
```

Currently, you may indicate which overload to use that way:

```
myPool.add(static_cast<std::string (MyClass::*) (std::string)>(&MyClass::doIt), a);
```

Note that `doIt` is a method (not a free function or static function), so you have to call it with an object.
If you add `static` to `doIt`, you may choose the overload with

```
myPool.add(static_cast<std::string (*) (std::string)>(&MyClass::doIt), a);
```

Comment: The first cast also needs to bind `this`.

Comment: Thank you for the lambda and casting solution! They indeed both work. Just have to decide now which is the least ugly, or rather which shows the intent in the clearest way.

Comment: @Ela782: the second way with lambda seems the clearest for me (you may prefer `[=]` for the capture).

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, the problem is that `doIt()` is not callable inside the `doIt_wrapper` class as it also needs a pointer to the object called on.
You could just modify the `doIt_wrapper` `operator()` to also take a pointer to the object and pass a pointer to `this` as first argument to `add()`.
It would then look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
using namespace std;

class Pool {
public:
    Pool() {};
    template<class F, class... A>
    auto add(F&& f, A&&... args) -> std::future<typename std::result_of<F&&(A&&...)>::type>
    {
        // return empty placeholder, for the sake of this code example
        std::future<typename std::result_of<F&&(A&&...)>::type> ret;
        return ret;
    };
};

class MyClass {
public:
     string doIt(string) { return string("a"); };
     string doIt(int, string) { return string("b"); };

     struct doIt_wrapper
     {
        template<class T, class... Ts>
        auto operator()(T&& t, Ts&&... args) -> decltype(t->doIt(std::forward<Ts>(args)...))
        {
           return t->doIt(std::forward<Ts>(args)...);
        }
     };

    void test() {
        Pool myPool;
        string a("test");
        myPool.add(doIt_wrapper(), this, a); // No error no more
    };
};

int main() {
   // your code goes here
   MyClass my;
   my.test();
   return 0;
}
```

This way you don't have to do the casts. The code compiles on both GCC and Clang.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out this solution and for correcting my wrapper-code! Good to know how to implement that option. Though I'm leaning towards the other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that non-static member functions have a hidden, implicit `this` parameter that points to the instance that called it. Your compiler is right to reject it as it doesn't have the correct arguments for the function. Sending in `this` as an additional bound parameter will work:

```
 myPool.add(&MyClass::doIt, this, a);
 //                         ^^^^
```

Using a lamda expression will work as well.

Also, the standard library function [`std::async()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) already does what you're trying to do here, and more. Consider using that instead.

---

**Edit:** You also need to cast to the correct type to select the correct overload. [@Jarod42](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26427477/701092) already shows you how.

Comment: Adding `this` won't solve the *overloading problem*.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about that hidden, implicit `this` parameter! Thank you very much! Thank you as well for pointing out std::async - of course I already know about it, but it doesn't quite do the same as a thread pool - If I call async 1000 times it might spawn 1000 threads while with a thread pool, there will only run x (e.g. x=8) threads at a time, grabbing work as it comes in.

Comment: On another note, I noticed today that std::async has the same limitations than my `add()` function - it can not resolve the ambiguity of overloaded member functions. In fact, it's a general (I guess technical) limitation of std::bind and there's no way around it except lambdas, casting or a wrapper! And I think all solutions are quite ugly. I just have to decide which one is least ugly, I'm leaning towards using a lambda or casting.